# SCCM Compliance state always 'Compliant' when remediation script runs

Tags: powershell, sccm

We're trying to use SCCM 2012 R2 to run some checks on clients and fix problems when needed. For this we use the PowerShell 'Script' option.

**Problem description:**

When a 'Discovery script' reports ‘Non-Compliant’ the ‘Remediation script’ is launched. Regardless of the output of the ‘Remediation script’, the result in the report on the client in ‘Configuration Manager > Configurations’ is always ‘Compliant’ even when the ‘Remediation script’ failed to fix the issue and as a result has different output then defined in the ‘Rules for compliance conditions’.

It seems that from the moment a ‘Remediation script’ is selected, the output of the SCCM Compliance State is always ‘Compliant’.

**Example:**

**- Situation:**

When there are files or folders in the folder ‘C:\Users\me\Downloads\Input_Test’ the ‘Discovery script’ reports ‘Not compliant to anything’ and kicks of the ‘Remediation script’. The remediation script takes action and can’t fix the problem so it reports back something else then ‘Compliant’, like ‘Non-Compliant’. The SCCM Compliance State should say after execution of the ‘Remediation script’: ‘Non-Compliant’ (which is not the case).

**- PowerShell Discovery script:**

```
$Paths = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\Input_Test' | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SCCMCompliance
if ($Paths) {
    $Compliance = 'Non-Compliant'
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SCCMCompliance -EntryType Warning -EventID 1 -Message “Discovery script: Non-Compliant”
}
else {
    $Compliance = 'Compliant'
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SCCMCompliance -EntryType Information -EventID 0 -Message “Discovery script: Compliant”
}
$Compliance
```

**- PowerShell Remediation script:**

```
Write-Output 'Non-Compliant'
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SCCMCompliance -EntryType Warning -EventID 1 -Message “Remediation script: Non-Compliant $Paths”
```

**- SCCM Rules for compliance conditions:**
 [image]
[image]

**- SCCM Compliance State in the Configuration Manager:**
 [image]

In the Windows event viewer all steps can be tracked easily. Am I missing something super obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain and hurt myself and @DarkLite1 have found that SCCM does not check compliance state after it has performed remediation

From the moment you use a 'Remediation script' the only 2 possible Compliance statusses are: 'Compliant' or 'Exit with error code'. This is done in PowerShell with 'Exit 1'.

For more information please see.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f0f3e6f-7e9f-4376-a926-fc0b6aef5bf1/sccm-compliance-state-always-compliant-when-remediation-script-runs?forum=configmanagersecurity

Comment: Do I also need to change the SCCM Compliance conditions?

Comment: Yeah, change it so compliant reads false, that basically means false means no files found and therefore compliant

Comment: Changed it like suggested 'Value equals FALSE' but it's still the same problem. The 'Discovery scripts' runs and sees it's incorrect, then the 'Remediation script' runs, this can be seen in the eventvwr. But the value in 'Compliance State' stays on 'Compliant' and the report reads 'Remediated Value: FALSE'.

Comment: and what happens if you remove | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SCCMCompliance

From the discovery script?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay just tested it in a powershell window, fails with the else in the first script, put the else immediately after the closing } on the if statement so it would be

If (stuff)
{
dostuff
}else
{stuff
}

Comment: Can you update your Answer to reflect what you mean?

Comment: and change the false in the compliance conditions back to compliant

Comment: The construct of if/else doesn't fail for me. I think this might be to your system not having PowerShell 4.0..

Comment: is that as a script or pasted into the powershell console though? i do have V4.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106466/discussion-between-darklite1-and-dewi-jones).

Comment: i think ive just realised what i was doing wrong here, give me 2 seconds