Sccm remediation scritpt always return true
I have a configuration item with a troubleshooting scenario. I know for a fact that my test host does not comply with the rule. But the troubleshooting script always returns true, although if I run the script locally on the host I get false as expected
I know that the file "C:\Windows\temp\biospwd.txt" doesn't exist on the host.
discovery:
# File detection script in user profile
$FileToDetect = "C:\Windows\Temp\biospwd.txt"
if (Test-Path $FileToDetect -PathType leaf) 
#File exists
{ return $True }
else
#File does not exist
{ return $false }

remedation:
# File detection script in user profile
$FileToDetect = "C:\Windows\Temp\biospwd.txt"
if (Test-Path $FileToDetect -PathType leaf)
#File exists
{ return $True }
else
#File does not exist
{ 
# Generate passhash
$biosserialNumber = (Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS).SerialNumber
$password = $biosserialNumber + "123"
$passwordBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($password)
$shaSHA512 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512]::Create()
$hashBytes = $shaSHA512.ComputeHash($passwordBytes)
$hashString = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hashBytes) -replace '-'
$hashString = $hashString.Substring(0, 14)
# Get the last boot time of the system
$lastBoottime = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime | Get-Date
# Define the path to the index file
$indexFilePath = "C:\Windows\Temp\BiosPasswordIndex.txt"
$biosPassTimeFilePath = "C:\Windows\Temp\BiosPassTime.txt"
# Check if the index file exists and read the index
if (Test-Path $indexFilePath) {
    $i = [int](Get-Content -Path $indexFilePath)
} else {
    $i = 0
}
# Get the last write time of the BiosPassTime.txt file
if (Test-Path $biosPassTimeFilePath) {
    $getfiletime = (Get-Item -Path $biosPassTimeFilePath).LastWriteTime
} else {
    $getfiletime = $null
}
# Check reboot condition and file existence
if (($lastBoottime -gt $getfiletime) -or ($null -eq $getfiletime)) {
    # List of passwords
    $passwords = @(
        "1", "2", "3", 
        "4"
    )
    [string]$MyPassword = $hashString
    $setPw = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_setBiosPassword -Namespace root\wmi
    # Iterate through passwords starting from index $i
    for ($j = $i; ($j -lt $passwords.Length) -and ($j -le ($i + 1)); $j++) {
        $currentPassword = $passwords[$j]
        $return = $setPw.SetBiosPassword("pap,$currentPassword,$MyPassword,ascii,us")
        if ($return.return -like "Success") {
            # Successful password change, create file and exit
            New-Item -Path "C:\windows\Temp" -ItemType File -Name "biospwd.txt" -Force -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
            # Remove the index file as the password has been successfully changed
            Remove-Item -Path $indexFilePath -Force | Out-Null
            #write-host $return.return
            return $true
        } else {
            # Failure, update the index and save it to the file
            
            Set-Content -Path $indexFilePath -Value ($j + 1) | Out-Null
           
            #write-host $return.return
        }
    }
    # If all attempts fail, create or update the last write time of the BiosPassTime.txt file
    New-Item -Path $biosPassTimeFilePath -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
   # write-host $return.return
    return $false
} else {return $false}
}

baseline:

compliance rule:

host report:

I don't understand why the host report returns true?
if you take out the remediation script and leave only the discovery script. Everything works as it should and I see non-compliant in the report.

answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033677/sccm-compliance-state-always-compliant-when-remediation-script-runs
